# Testing an iPhone app on an iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing

I'm working on an iPhone app but my iPhone just died and buying another one just for testing is prohibitively expensive. If I'm not using iPhone specific features like making calls, could I use an iPad 2 for testing or are there differences in architecture that would cause iPhone-specific bugs to go uncaught? I've still got the simulator for working on layouts and general testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine, although I would borrow an iPhone or something to do some testing before the final release.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine. Just like when you setup your iPhone, you will have to give the iPad a provisioning profile. I've developed games for the iPhone and seamlessly ported them to the iPad. There are differences, but apple handles this. Basically you can run iPhone apps on an iPad, but a lot of times, not the other way around.

Here are some steps:

1. Get a provisioning profile for the iPad from the apple developers portal
2. Set it up on your iPad
3. Open xcode and select the ipad from the Scheme dropdown.
4. click run, see what breaks! It will tell you if you haven't setup your profile correctly here.

I agree with the other answer too, you should definitely test it on every device you intend on releasing it for. There are architectural differences on all of the devices and all need to be tested thoroughly. You tend to get bad reviews if you overlooked testing a device.

Answer (score 1):

You can. but keep in mind that not everything works as it should. Picture and Music pickers are both a little funky, appearing in the wrong place and such. Speed is also an issue, as the iPad is much faster than the 3G and 3GS phones. Defiantly test on a phone before release, or buy an old iPod Touch.

Comment: Except Cocos2D (OpenGL) seems to be a lot slower on the iPad than the iPod Touch 4 (with nearly as many pixels).